# xPath evaluation returns null for node, but count() function shows that there are values

Tags: java, xml

I am counting how many nodes I get for a specific xpath and then iterating through these nodes.

For a particular xpath, the count is 6. The first 4 nodes appear with values. When I reach the 5th and 6th, I get nulls.

The XML looks roughly like this

```
<account>
    <contact>
    <contact>
    <contact>
    <contact>
</account>
<account>
    <contact>
    <contact>
</account>
```

Here is a code snippet:

```
String count = xpath.evaluate("count("+genericPath+")", LegacyXML);
                  System.out.println("count " +count);


                  for (int a = 1; a <= Integer.valueOf(count); a++){
                      XPathExpression genPath = xpath.compile(genericPath+"["+a+"]");
                      Object result = genPath.evaluate(LegacyXML, XPathConstants.NODE);
                      Node nodes = (Node) result; 

                      Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
                      try{
                          doc.appendChild(doc.importNode(nodes, true));
                          System.out.println("this is eval result :) "+ xpath.evaluate(genericPath+"["+a+"]", LegacyXML).toString());

                      }catch(NullPointerException e){
                          System.out.println("Please ensure that the hierarchy code of" +PKattribute+ " in " +LegacyAPI + " is correct. It doesn't point to an array.");
                          System.out.println("this is eval result :( "+ xpath.evaluate(genericPath+"["+a+"]", LegacyXML).toString());



  }
```

So I am getting the first 4 nodes properly, the last two are null. When I open the XML and look at it, there are clearly values present. Testing the variable 'genericPath' on various online xPath evaluates returns 6 nodes with values. What am I missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: genericPath = //*contact

Comment: what is the exact value of genericPath?

Comment: I edited the question. In reality, it’s something along the lines of //*[localname()=‘contact’].

Comment: You are counting outside the loop and evaluating inside it. It would be better if you evaluate genericPath outside the loop and iterate the NodeList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the generic path is `//contact` then it will select 6 elements.

`//contact[N]` selects every contact that is the Nth child of its parent. Therefore `//contact[5]` and `//contact[6]` select nothing.

You want `(//contact)[N]`.

Constructing expressions like this repeatedly using string concatenation is incredibly inefficient. Parsing and compiling an XPath expression like this probably takes 100 times as long as executing it. Much better to compile a single expression with a parameter that can be supplied at run-time. Or even better, evaluate a single expression that returns all six elements.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Your points are well taken, but requirements are requirements...

Comment: What on earth does "requirements are requirements" mean? Is someone requiring you to write the code inefficiently?